# Python Pandas groupby: how to do conditional aggregation dependent on other column

Tags: python, filter, conditional-statements, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I would like to use Panda's groupby with multiple aggregation functions, but also including conditional statements per aggregation. Imagine having this data as an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
    'type': ['in_scope', 'in_scope', 'exclude', 'in_scope', 'exclude'],
    'value': [5, 5, 99, 20, 99]
})
```

```
INPUT DATA:
| id | in_scope | value |
|----|----------|-------|
| a  | True     | 5     |
| a  | True     | 5     |
| a  | False    | 99    |
| b  | True     | 20    |
| b  | False    | 99    |
```

And I want to do a Pandas groupby like this:

```
df.groupby('id').agg(
    num_records=('id', 'size'),
    sum_value=('value', np.sum)
)
```

```
OUTPUT OF SIMPLE GROUPBY:
| id | num_records | sum_value |
|----|-------------|-----------|
| a  | 3           | 109       |
| b  | 2           | 119       |
```

However, I would like to do the sum depending on a condition, namely that only the "in_scope" records that are defined as `True` in column `in_scope` should be used. Note, the first aggregation should still use the entire table. In short, this is the desired output:

```
DESIRED OUTPUT OF GROUPBY:
| id | num_records | sum_value_in_scope |
|----|-------------|--------------------|
| a  | 3           | 10                 |
| b  | 2           | 20                 |
```

I was thinking about passing two arguments to a lambda function, but I do not succeed. Of course, it can be solved by performing two separate groupbys on filtered and unfiltered data and combine them together afterwards. But I was hoping there was a shorter and more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer: Create a temporary column that contains values only when `type` is `in_scope`, then aggregate:

```
(
    df.assign(temp=np.where(df["type"] == "in_scope", df["value"], None))
    .groupby("id", as_index=False)
    .agg(num_records=("type", "size"), sum_value=("temp", "sum"))
)
    
id   num_records    sum_value   
a       3             10
b       2             20
```

Comment: Just noticed the updated answer, I think this is very clean and the preferred way as far as I can imagine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this with aggregate, however you can do it in one step with apply and a custom function:

```py
def f(x):
    d = {}
    d['num_records'] = len(x)
    d['sum_value_in_scope'] = x[x.in_scope].value.sum()
    return pd.Series(d, index=['num_records', 'sum_value_in_scope'])

df.groupby('id').apply(f)
```

Since the column `df.in_scope` is already boolean, you can use it as a mask directly to filter the values which are summed. If the column you are working with is not boolean, it is better to use `df.query('<your query here>')` to get the subset of the data (there are optimizations under the hood which make it faster than most other methods).

Comment: Good approach, thanks!

Regarding the `query` method, in my experience that is only faster when using multiple conditions. [I like the example given here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html#Performance:-When-to-Use-These-Functions]), that seems to match my experience too.